How does `min-height` affect flex item's size calculation?
I have 3 nesting html components, lets call them A, B, and C.
A fills the viewport, has:
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;

B has:
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 8px;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 0;

And C's height is super high.
Currently, it works fine, C will be shrunk to the viewport height and the overflow of C's child will work (there will be a scrollbar in C's child). However, if I remove the min-height:0 on B, C will stretch B and make it higher than the viewport.
Why is the min-height: 0 important? How does it affect height calculation, is there any documentation? The MDN page of min-height didn't say anything about this.

Please provide a working code example.
